# How can I maximize the browser window while running test scripts in casperjs using slimerjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs, slimerjs

I'm unable to view the full window while running test scripts in casperjs using slimerjs engine . could any one please help me to increase the mozila browser window size

Answer (score 15):

Sure, use the phantom/slimer viewportSize option in casper :

```
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1600, height: 950};
```

Or the casper function :

```
casper.start(url)
.viewport(1600,1000)
.{...}
```

With the function you can easily change the window size during steps of a scenario.

And the scrollTo(), srollToBottom() functions should help you too : http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#scrollto

Comment: Any idea how to detect screen size, so as to provide parameters width and height that are optimal for user running the script ?

Comment: Do you mean that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("http://slimerjs.org", function (status) {
    page.viewportSize = { width:1024, height:768 };
    page.render('screenshot.png')
});
```

[viewportSize allows you to set the window size.](http://docs.slimerjs.org/0.9/quick-start.html#taking-screenshots)