# Set Screen size in PhantomJS/CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, screen-size

I'm automating access to a web site to collect data from it. Unfortunately that page detects the screen size and doesn't give me the desired page if the screen is too small. When running the script from a non-interactive context (IIS web application) the Screen object seems to return a size of 1024x768 pixels. Even though I set the viewport size to 1300x1000 pixels which affects screenshots but not the web page's JavaScript.

How can I tell PhantomJS or CasperJS (I'm using the latter but that's using the former) to return different values for the Screen object in page's JavaScript?

Edit: This is CasperJS, not PhantomJS, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override window.screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045727/how-do-i-override-window-screen)

Comment: Basically yes, but it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it works with CasperJS:

```
// at the start of the script file
var casper = require("casper").create({
    // other options here
    onPageInitialized: function (page) {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            window.screen = {
                width: 1920,
                height: 1080
            };
        });
    }
});

// script goes on here
```

Answer (score 10):

According [official documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#viewportsize) you can do it using **viewportSize** option.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    // other options here
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    }
});
```

It will be more lightweight solution than overriding viewport size after each page loading.

Answer (score 1):

Another option like you [can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22858886/3377046):

```
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1600, height: 950};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set by this as well while defining functions:

```
casper.viewport(1300, 1000).then(function () {
     test.assertUrlMatches(/testing\.html$/);
});
```

Comment: That's what I did and mentioned in my question. The viewport is not what the screen object reports to the page's script.