# How can I generate high DPI mobile-like screenshots with CasperJS/PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I can [set the viewportSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858088/how-can-i-maximize-the-browser-window-while-running-test-scripts-in-casperjs-usi) to get small mobile layout & sized screenshots:

```
// 1080 x 1920 is Nexus 5 resolution
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1080 / 3, height: 1920 / 3};
```

However the DPI is low, unlike when viewed on mobile.

#### Related info

My page [uses the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) like so

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 1):

What we really need is to set the [Device Pixel Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio). It appears as of July 2016, [PhantomJS is lacking that ability](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10964), however [people are working on it](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/13942).

Answer (score 0):

Keep full resolution, and use [Casper's zoom](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#zoom)

```
// 1080 x 1920 is Nexus 5 resolution
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1080, height: 1920};
casper.start().zoom(3)
```

This will probably fail under responsive designs with @media queries relative to screen size.  I'm still hoping for a less hackish answer, but this at least gets us a little closer.